# How do I restore MySQL DB from backup

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-backup

My server recently crashed and I have backed the Mysql files using raid.

BACKED UP DIRECTORY

```
/backup/var/lib/mysql
```

I installed new `OS(RHEL5.3)` to my server and I want to restore my DB to MySQL

How do I do this?
I know you can `ssh mysql > the dump files`
but,  these backed up files are not in DUMP.
They are separated as `.MYD .MYI .frm` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your backup file is not in the same server as your database.

Try:

`scp -r /backup/var/lib/mysql/* DB_SERVER:YOUR_NEW_DATABASE_DIRECTORY`

Then

```
ssh DB_SERVER
.. restart your mysql daemon (easier)
.. or flush privileges, flush tables ...
```

Comment: so would I run something like this? scp -r /backup/var/lib/mysql/blog_db DB_SERVER:/var/lib/mysql/blog_db

Comment: @Maca - Yes. Take note each database is actually has a directory on it. So, in your DB_SERVER, both need to matchable. Or you do a scp per directory at one time.

Comment: I have tried scp -r /backup/var/lib/mysql/blog_db /var/lib/mysql/blog_db but it didn't copy nor gave an error.  somthing doing wrong?

Comment: Did you include your database host ? It should be like `scp -r /backup/var/lib/mysql/blog_db YOUR_DATABASE:/var/lib/mysql/blog_db ... also, please ensure the path `/var/lib/mysql/` is exist in your database server

Comment: Still no luck. I have put scp -r /backup/var/lib/mysql/blog_db blog_db:/var/lib/mysql/blog_db and I received "ssh: blog_db: Name or service not known lost connection"

Comment: @Maca - Are you sure the blog_db is the actual database server ? And do you have the login ?

Comment: Just scp -r /backup/var/lib/mysql/blog_db /var/lib/mysql/blog_db alone worked thanks!

Comment: Oh, so both backup server and database is the same server?

Answer (score 0):

Copy these files directly to your mysql data directory, and you will be able to access them in MySQL. That should help you!